# Qt: Symbol undefined when inheriting from QObject

Tags: qt, signals-slots, undefined-symbol

I'm new to Qt and tried to compile an example from the Qt pages (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) that implements a simple class with a signal and a slot. Both when using Qt Creator and qmake by itself I get the following error message:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "Counter::valueChanged(int)", referenced from:
>         Counter::setValue(int) in main.o
>         _main in main.o   "vtable for Counter", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o

Any thoughts...? Answers to similar questions involved running qmake, but as I said, this produces the same error in this case. Thanks!

```
#include <QObject>

class Counter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Counter() { m_value = 0; }

    int value() const { return m_value; }

public slots:
    void setValue(int value);

signals:
    void valueChanged(int newValue);

private:
    int m_value;
};

void Counter::setValue(int value)
{
    if (value != m_value) {
        m_value = value;
        emit valueChanged(value);
    }
}


int main()
{
    Counter a, b;
        QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                         &b, SLOT(setValue(int)));

        a.setValue(12);     // a.value() == 12, b.value() == 12
        b.setValue(48);     // a.value() == 12, b.value() == 48
}
```

Comment: Include the `moc` file at the end of your file (after main; btw you are missing `return 0` there ;)) and try again.

Comment: Thanks, that works!

Comment: Np. This is a common problem.

Comment: Usually classes with the Q_OBJECT macro are declared in header files and these headers are part of the `HEADERS` entry in the project's `.pro` file. That way you don't need to include the moc file, it will be compiled separately and linked into the final program